# How can I know the size in kb/mb of each model or other element present in my file?

Tags: export, blend-files, gltf

Can I read it somewhere in Blender or can I obtain a text file or whatever exporting the file in some format (maybe gltf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're exporting the scene to glTF, it's possible to get a printout of the size of each part of the file using the [glTF-Transform CLI](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/cli.html), or its JS library, or the related https://gltf.report/ web tool.

Example:

```
npm install --global @gltf-transform/cli
gltf-transform inspect input.glb
```

Output:

```
METADATA
 ────────────────────────────────────────────
┌────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ key                │ value                │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ version            │ 2.0                  │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ generator          │ <software version>   │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ extensionsUsed     │ none                 │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ extensionsRequired │ none                 │
└────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘



 SCENES
 ────────────────────────────────────────────
┌───┬──────┬─────────────┬──────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ # │ name │ rootName    │ bboxMin                      │ bboxMax                   │
├───┼──────┼─────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┤
│ 0 │      │ WaterBottle │ -0.05445, -0.13022, -0.05445 │ 0.05445, 0.13022, 0.05445 │
└───┴──────┴─────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘



 MESHES
 ────────────────────────────────────────────
┌───┬─────────────┬───────────┬────────────┬──────────────┬──────────┬─────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ # │ name        │ mode      │ primitives │ glPrimitives │ vertices │ indices │ attributes                                                            │ instances │ size¹     │
├───┼─────────────┼───────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 0 │ WaterBottle │ TRIANGLES │ 1          │ 4,510        │ 2,549    │ uint16  │ NORMAL:float32, POSITION:float32, TANGENT:float32, TEXCOORD_0:float32 │ 1         │ 145.91 KB │
└───┴─────────────┴───────────┴────────────┴──────────────┴──────────┴─────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘

¹ size estimates GPU memory required by a mesh, in isolation. If accessors are
  shared by other mesh primitives, but the meshes themselves are not reused, then
  the sum of all mesh sizes will overestimate the asset's total size. See "dedup".



 MATERIALS
 ────────────────────────────────────────────
┌───┬───────────┬───────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬─────────────┐
│ # │ name      │ instances │ textures                                                                                     │ alphaMode │ doubleSided │
├───┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│ 0 │ BottleMat │ 1         │ baseColorTexture, emissiveTexture, normalTexture, occlusionTexture, metallicRoughnessTexture │ OPAQUE    │             │
└───┴───────────┴───────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴─────────────┘



 TEXTURES
 ────────────────────────────────────────────
┌───┬──────┬─────┬────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬────────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ # │ name │ uri │ slots                                      │ instances │ mimeType  │ resolution │ size     │ gpuSize¹ │
├───┼──────┼─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0 │      │     │ baseColorTexture                           │ 1         │ image/png │ 2048x2048  │ 2.07 MB  │ 21.33 MB │
├───┼──────┼─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1 │      │     │ occlusionTexture, metallicRoughnessTexture │ 2         │ image/png │ 2048x2048  │ 3.41 MB  │ 21.33 MB │
├───┼──────┼─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 2 │      │     │ normalTexture                              │ 1         │ image/png │ 2048x2048  │ 2.87 MB  │ 21.33 MB │
├───┼──────┼─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 3 │      │     │ emissiveTexture                            │ 1         │ image/png │ 2048x2048  │ 57.72 KB │ 21.33 MB │
└───┴──────┴─────┴────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴────────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

¹ gpuSize estimates minimum GPU memory allocation. Older devices may require
  additional memory for GPU compression formats.



 ANIMATIONS
 ────────────────────────────────────────────
No animations found.
```

Exporting to other formats will likely result in different sizes, as each format uses different representations of the data.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what I was searching for!